# When is there a representer theorem?

Tags: optimization, error, regularization, loss-functions

The case of regularization in a hilbert space is considered---an optimization problem with an error term and a Tikhonov-regularizer.

In the article ["When is there a representer theorem"](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~argyriou/papers/representer.pdf) it is stated on page 2 (2508), and proofs are referred to, that the representer theorem holds when the regularizer is a *nondecreasing* function of the norm, i.e. square of the hilbert space norm.

Are there any other requirements on the problem, for example on the error term?

Answer (score 3):

Scholkopf et al,["A Generalised Representer Theorem](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P139.pdf), suggests that the loss function can be arbitrary.  I suspect the kernel function must be positive-definite for the representer theorem to hold as well.  However, it is a very long time since I last looked at that sort of thing, so there may well have been something I have overlooked.